# Understanding RxJava observable when underlying data source has new values

Tags: java, rx-java

I am trying to experiment RxJava observable and observer code. My objective is to check that how things work when underlying source receives new data values. My code is as:

```
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int i = 100;
                while(i < 110) {
                    numbers.add(i);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(10);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    i++;
                }
            }
        };
        numbers.add(0);
        numbers.add(1);
        numbers.add(2);
        Observable.fromIterable(numbers)
                .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(i -> System.out.println("Received "+i+ " on "+ Thread.currentThread().getName()),
                        e -> e.printStackTrace());
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Thread t = new Thread(r);
        t.start();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

So I have a list of numbers. I then have a runnable which adds new numbers to this list with a time gap between the additions. I don't start thread yet. I add 0,1,2 to the list and then create an observable with it, scheduling the observer on a thread from pool, and finally subscribing to the observable. As subscription happens, observable emits the values 0,1,2 and observer is invoked(lambda passed to subscribe is executed). Then I introduce a delay of 1 sec on the main thread and then I spawn a new thread using runnable I created earlier, and also add a final delay so that application doesn't exit immediately.

What I expect is that as new numbers are added to the list, observer must be invoked, thus printing the message. But that doesn't happen. Surely I have got it wrong in my understanding. Do I need to also put observable on a scheduler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Observable.fromIterable()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#fromIterable-java.lang.Iterable-) method is a "one time" load of values for an observable each time a subscription is build. What happens "after" building the subscription has no affect anymore. When you use the [`subscribe(onNext, onError, onComplete)`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#subscribe-io.reactivex.functions.Consumer-io.reactivex.functions.Consumer-io.reactivex.functions.Action-) method with the `onComplete` argument you will see that the subscription has fully consumed and the three initial values has been printed.

You can use a [`Subject`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/subjects/Subject.html) (something like a [`PublishSubject`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/subjects/PublishSubject.html)) where you use the `onNext()` method to add "new values" while the subscriptions which were built earlier are still active (and not completed). That way you can build the subscriptions first and keep calling `onNext()` for new values in the subject until you are done and call `onCompleted()`.